# Navigator no aparece MySQL Workbench

Tags: mysql, base-de-datos, mysql-workbench

Simplemente no aparece navigator, donde uno podria ver Schemas y administrarion, no me aparece
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Answer (score 0):

Hola ya me aparece jaja tenes que ir a view y darle show en paneles, y despues irte hasta la esquina y arrastra si no aparece
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]